# Google Maps Display State Lines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a custom mapstyle in https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/, and tried to apply a border between the states, but the default border style is doted. I was wondering if is possible to change to a line border.

See the picture below:

[image]

Can someone give me some tips on how to achieve that? or how to achieve the same purpose in another way? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs on `stylers`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference#stylers) there is no option to change the stroke type to a solid line unfortunately.

```
{
"featureType": "administrative.province",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  {
    "color": "#ff3c3c" //no option avilable for stroke type
  }
]
}
```